# C++ linked List nodes not changing

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list, reverse, singly-linked-list

I am trying to reorder Linked List such that given linked list (Head),

> L0 → L1 → … → Ln - 1 → Ln

changes to,

> L0 → Ln → L1 → Ln - 1 → L2 → Ln - 2 → …

```
    void reorderList(ListNode* head) {
        ListNode* h=head;
        map<int,ListNode*> allNodes;
        int count=0;
        while(h!=nullptr){
            ListNode* temp=new ListNode(h->val);
            allNodes[count]=temp;
            count++;
            h=h->next;
        }
        auto rItr=allNodes.rbegin();
        auto itr=allNodes.begin();
        head=nullptr;// tried with and without this line same result
        while(itr->first!=rItr->first){
            head=itr->second;
            head=head->next;
            head=rItr->second;
            itr++;
            rItr++;
            head=head->next;
        }
        head=itr->second;

    }
```

> I am creating new nodes and storing them in the map, Why is the Linked List not getting updated?

Input [1,2,3,4,5]

Expected output:
[1,5,2,4,3]

Actual Output
[1,2,3,4,5]

That is no change

Comment: @rushikesh chaskar you passed the pointer to the head node by value.  That is the function deals with a copy of the pointer to the head node. Changing the copy does not influence on the original pointer.

Comment: As a side note: if you are going to use a map, then why use a linked list at all? If this is a code challenge, the intent is that you don't use O(n) auxiliary memory.

Comment: Is this using a doubly linked list or a singular linked list.  A doubly linked list would be easier.

Comment: At no point do you change a node's `next` pointer, which would be how to modify the order of a list.  You're only doing **many** reassignments to the local variable `head`.

Comment: @trincot well, I needed to somehow traverse the linked list from the back as well for changing the values, I couldn't find any way to traverse the same list backwards without auxiliary space... the list isn't doubly-linked.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews no its not doubly-linked..

Comment: Why use a `map` to store values at indices `0, ..., n`? just use a `std::vector<ListNode*>` furthermore: why do you dynamically allocate new nodes? Assuming the output is the desired result you've got a memory leak somewhere, since there are no deletes; if not your function must be wrong, since you've doubled the number of elements. You just need to create a permutation of the list, so if you're efficient, you won't need to allocate or delete any nodes.

Comment: @rushikeshchaskar, it is possible without O(n) auxiliary space. Hint: Look up how to reverse a singly linked list with O(1) auxiliary space. It is related.

Answer (score 1):

To make the assignment there is no need to allocate new nodes. Moreover it is inefficient and requires additional memory.

Pay attention to that within your function you are changing the pointer to the head node but the original pointer to the head node is passed to the function by value. That is the function deals with a copy of the value of the original pointer to the head node. Changing the copy does not influence on the value stored in the original pointer to the head node.

As an idea I can suggest the following approach to the assignment.

- First, find the middle of the list. Using the middle split the list
  into two lists.
- Second, reverse the second list.
- Third, combine the two lists in one list.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows the approach using the standard container `std::forward_list` that represents a singly-linked list (it is not a production code.:)).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <forward_list>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T>
typename std::forward_list<T>::const_iterator 
find_middle( const std::forward_list<T> &list )
{
    auto middle = std::begin( list );
    
    for ( auto last = std::begin( list ); 
          last != std::end( list ) && ( std::advance( last, 1 ), last != std::end( list ) );
          std::advance( last, 1 )  )
    {
        std::advance( middle, 1 );
    }
    
    return middle;
}

template <typename T>
void merge( std::forward_list<T> &first, std::forward_list<T> &second )
{
    for ( auto position = std::begin( first ); 
          position != std::end( first ) && !second.empty(); )
    {
        position = first.insert_after( position, second.front() );
        std::advance( position, 1 );
        second.erase_after( second.before_begin() );
    }
    
    if ( !second.empty() )
    {
        first.insert_after( std::end( first ), std::begin( second ), std::end( second ) );
        second.clear();
    }
}

int main() 
{
    std::forward_list<int> first = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    
    for ( const auto &current : first )
    {
        std::cout << current << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << '\n';
    
    auto middle = find_middle( first );
    
    if ( middle != std::begin( first ) )
    {
        std::forward_list<int> second;
        
        second.splice_after( second.before_begin(), first, middle, std::cend( first ) );
        
        for ( const auto &current : first )
        {
            std::cout << current << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';

        for ( const auto &current : second )
        {
            std::cout << current << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
        
        std::cout << '\n';
    
        second.reverse();
        
        for ( const auto &current : first )
        {
            std::cout << current << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';

        for ( const auto &current : second )
        {
            std::cout << current << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
        
        std::cout << '\n';
    
        merge( first, second );

        for ( const auto &current : first )
        {
            std::cout << current << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';

        for ( const auto &current : second )
        {
            std::cout << current << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 

1 2 3 
4 5 

1 2 3 
5 4 

1 5 2 4 3
```

So what you need is to write a function that finds the middle node (similar to the function `find_middle` shown in the demonstrative program). Then to write a function that splits a list based on the middle node into two lists. Then to write a function that reverses a singly-linked list. And then it will be easy to write a function that combines two list in one list.